# Lease on VHD after Blob Copy (start-azurestorageblobcopy)

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I've noticed in the last few weeks (could be longer) that after copying a VHD, when I try to create a VHD to create a VM, I get a message stating that there's still a lease on the blob. After several hours the message goes away and I can proceed. I tried checking the status for the copy, but it always says that it's complete.  I'm creating VHD's and VM's with new names, so no conflicts with old VMs. Is there any way of quickly telling when the lease is released?  I'm using Azure PowerShell 1.0.1 I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the PowerShell code below to quickly get the status of your blob lease.

```
$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <storageAccountName> -StorageAccountKey <storageAccountKey>
$Blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container <containerName> -Blob <blobName> -Context $Context
$BlobLeaseStatus = $Blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.LeaseStatus
```

Comment: Thanks, that would probably do the trick.  However, further investigation made me realize that the Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyStatus has changed, so I decided just to use the --WaitForComplete option there instead.